# Globally uncaught exception shown in the RHQ UI when trying to add/edit users

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, rhq

We are using RHQ for monitoring the services, while creating a user we are getting an globally uncaught exception with below details on browser console.

Cannot read property **getRecords**' of null

**com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException** Cannot read property **getRecords** of null

Cannot read property 'getRecords' of null

More details:
Tested on Chrome, IE 11, and Firefox 43.0.4

RHQ version: 4.13.1, technologies used in this GWT, Smart GWT

Can any one please help on knowing how can we debug this RHQ?
I have little understanding on the GWT and debugging GWT but that is not helping us.

Are there any other ways to debug? Not addressed the bug details still in bugzilla 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1315257

Thank you.

Comment: To debug you have to build it from sources. In this case you can skip obfuscating and build source maps for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error should be harmless, it'll create the user, you can ignore it. I've fixed it in the master, check the PR https://github.com/rhq-project/rhq/pull/258

Comment: Hmm.., Logically its not. We are unable present to our clients due to this unreasonable error on page. Thank you for fixing.